# Request.UserHostAddress issue with return result "::1"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ip, httpcontext

I am trying to get client ip address using

```
    HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

but it returns `::1`.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`::1` is for `localhost`, Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/174715/is-there-a-way-to-disable-ipv6-in-googles-chrome)
might be useful.

Answer (score 30):

This is not a bug - you're connecting from [localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) on an [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipv6) enabled machine.  `::1` is the loopback address - [a double colon means "omitted zeroes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_Format), so this address corresponds to address 1.

If you're developing *new* software, I'd urge you *not* to disable IPv6.  The easiest time to implement support is right from the start, and spending time on workarounds is perhaps just wasting effort putting off the inevitable.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's true that this is not a bug, maybe you can check [this link](http://redhead-it.com/blog/2009/05/httpcontextcurrentrequestuserhostaddress-returns-1/), where your problem is nicely described and "solved". It says that the way the issue behaves depends on the operating system, since a user fixed some problems in an application running in *Windows Server 2008* by commenting the `::1` line in the *hosts* file, while he had to uncomment it in *Windows 7*.

Hope you managed to solve that! Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you like to edit your post, to include an excerpt of the article? That way, your answer will remain useful if the link dies.

Comment: Sure! Just about to do it. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I could not reach the link, can you check it, please @FranciscoBouza

Answer (score 2):

it is not bug actually you are running your application on local host it is just giving you the ip of of local host and it is ipv6 format