# how to get client Ip address when the request is made from javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

i want to get the client IP address who makes the request to my site.
here is some code to get this:

```
 var w2 = HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
 var w3 = this.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

this works fine when the request comes from browser.
but when the request comes from javascript  i don't get the results excpected.

here is my javascript requset:

```
<script src="http://localhost:55866/Dashboard/GetCampine?MediaId=21&ProductsTypId=5 "> 
    </script>
```

that is what i get:
w3=::1 w2=::1

Comment: `::1` Looks like the IPv6 loopback address (local address of your computer), it's the expected value if you are testing on `localhost`. Also you question is probably not about javascript.

Comment: It's only when you're testing your code in `localhost` that you're seeing `::1` as the client host (it's the local address of the IPv6 loopback interface). Also, there shouldn't be any difference when the request is initiated by regular / Ajax request (in terms of client info).

Comment: It's `localhost` for IPv6. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408957/request-userhostaddress-issue-with-return-result-1).