# Issue in getting client IP address in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get the client IP address in m global.cs file. I'm using Request.UserHostAddress but it's returning only "::1" not the whole IP address and also tried `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` but no use.

Comment: This is because you are running with localhost, once you upload your web on live you will get the output as expected.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/10517371/1433093

Comment: This is not a bug, “::1” is a perfectly legal IPv6 address and is the IPv6 equiv. of 127.0.0.1.As said by Kundan you will get perfect result once you host the application. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408957/request-userhostaddress-issue-with-return-result-1