# HttpContextAccessor not retrieving property values in Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I am trying to retrieve the remote Ip Address of the registrant on my registration page.

For testing, I am using a test app.
In the controller;

```
private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    public HomeController(IConfiguration config, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _config = config;
        _accessor = accessor;
    }
```

and in the action result

```
 var ipAddress = _accessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

that code is erring with the error message

> - Address 'ipAddress.Address' threw an exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' long {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}
>       Message "The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced"    string

I did NOT add a services call in Startup for the HttpContextAccessor because in reading about it, it is set up by default in Core 2.

UPDATE:
I also tried using the X-Forwarded-For middleware as suggested by this blogpost
[X-Forwarded-For](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnetcore-geo-location-from-ip-address/)

but it still resolves to ::1 as the Ip address. Most likely because that middleware isn't working, Fiddler doesn't show the X-Forwarded-For in the headers

Any help appreciated as to why this error is occurring.

Comment: Any answer here can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into controller. Instead just use `Request.HttpContext` property of controller that returns context for the executing request:

```
public HomeController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string ActionMethod()
    {
        var address = this.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Set...That still returns the same thing... {::1} System.Net.IPAddress...which clearly is not an Ip address. Does it have anything to do with the fact I'm testing with localhost?

Comment: @dinotom yes, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408957/request-userhostaddress-issue-with-return-result-1

Comment: @Set...I changed the host file already. That doesn't solve it either. It is a socket exception error, that's what bugs me